# how to convert android contacts date-of birth-string to date format?

Tags: android

In my Android project i want to convert contacts date-of-birth as **string to date** from user locale.

```
  String whereBday = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" + 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;

     String[] paramsBday = new String[]{ 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE   };

    Cursor bDayCursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,  whereBday, paramsBday, null); 

    while (bDayCursor.moveToNext()) { 

//date of birth as String format
        String bDay = bDayCursor.getString(bDayCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE));
       //converting string to date format
       SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(bDay);
        Date myDate= formatter.parse(mytime);
        DateFormat f = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
        String formattedDate = f.format(new Date());
        System.out.println("Date: " + formattedDate);

    }

     bDayCursor.close();
```

Comment: convert android contacts date-of birth-string to date format

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems that there is no fixed standard as to what the date format is stored in. The best solution is to loop through a list of date formats, and see if it matches any of the following. And once you get the `date` object you can modify it to be printed in any format using your own formatter. Also if its not found, then you can check the format which is not supported, and add it in your array.

You can use the following code:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat[] birthdayFormats = {
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("yy.MM.dd"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd"),
        new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy")
};

private void printBirthdays() {
    Cursor cursor = getContactsBirthdays();
    int bDayColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String bDay = cursor.getString(bDayColumn);
        Date birthday = null;
        boolean found = false;
        for (SimpleDateFormat f : birthdayFormats) {
            try {
                birthday = f.parse(bDay);
                Log.e(TAG, bDay + " = " + birthday.toString());
                found = true;
                break;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            Log.e(TAG, bDay);
        }
    }
}

private Cursor getContactsBirthdays() {
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTACT_ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.START_DATE
    };

    String where =
            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "= ? AND " +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE + "=" +
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.TYPE_BIRTHDAY;
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
    };
    String sortOrder = null;
    return managedQuery(uri, projection, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```